# Agregar ubicacion de marcadores - Google Maps

Tags: java, android

Tengo una aplicación de Android en Java en donde estoy agregando el Activity y la clase de Google Maps. Mi idea es mandarle por parámetro a la función `OnMapReady` o establecer de alguna manera una ubicación personalizada, ya que quiero que cada vez que se abra el mapa, se abra con un marker distinto dependiendo de dónde venga. Probé lo siguiente:

```
public class MapsActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private double latitud;
    private double longitud;
private LatLng ubicacion;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = ubicacion;
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Ubicacion Gasto"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    public void setearUbicacion(double lat, double longi){
         ubicacion = new LatLng(lat, longi);
    }
}
```

Pero llega nulo cuando se inicializa `onMapReady`. ¿Cómo podría hacer?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que agregas en tu pregunta es el ejemplo de la documentacion oficial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker

El problema por el cual obtienes un valor null del mapa es provocado porque **no estas definiendo la geoposiciòn del marcador**, para esto veo que tienes el mètodo `setearUbicacion()`, debes llamar este mètodo y definir la ubicaciòn antes de tratar de cargar el Fragment, ejemplo:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

        //*Define ubicaciòn.
        setearUbicacion(-33.852, 151.211);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias!! Pude hacerlo con esto y mandando la longitud y latitud mediante bundle entre activities :D